# How can I disable the GZipEncoder per endpoint?

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I have endpoints hit by browsers which always provide the "gzip" accepted encoding.  However, for some endpoints I want to avoid the extra cpu processing required to gzip (they are returning already compressed data).  Is there a way to signal to the GZipEncoder that "I don't want this to apply to these endpoints"?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating a DynamicFeature and annotation which, when combined, removes accept encodings of gzip, br, and deflate.  I'm not sure if that is the best way but it works.

The docs

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/DynamicFeature.html

The example I followed

https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.java